# Doctrine DQL "inclusive or"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, bitwise-or

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve a simple "**inclusive or**" in **Doctrine DQL** ?

I can do the following in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM Status WHERE `isGenerated`|`isGeneratable`=:flag;
```

**or**

```
SELECT * FROM Status WHERE :flag IN (`isGenerated`,`isGeneratable`);
```

**But** neither of these work in DQL

**Solution** can't answer my own question yet :/

```
SELECT s FROM FooBundle:Status s WHERE BIT_OR(s.isGenerated,s.isGeneratable)=:flag
```

Comment: Are these booleans or numbers that will go above 1?

Comment: Booleans, isGenerated and isGeneratable are tinyints

Comment: and what's the problem with the last query? I think that is correct because your are `triggering the column for a specific value`.

Comment: What's wrong with `s.isGenerated OR s.isGeneratable`?  Which would be the standard way to do that.

Comment: There are several ways to use `IN()` function in doctrine using the last query you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't support `|` but supports `BIT_OR()`

**Solution** :

```
SELECT s FROM FooBundle:Status s WHERE BIT_OR(s.isGenerated, s.isGeneratable)=:flag
```